# Google Dictionary API not working--is there another solution?

Tags: api, dictionary

I have been using the Google Dictionary API and accessing it with this url:

http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&q='test'&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr,de&client=te

However, now this url throws an error.

Then, I found this site: http://google-dictionary.so8848.com/meaning?word=test and this works fine.  Digging around their site I found the same url as mine in their code.  Yet, when copied and pasted into a browser also throws an error.

So, I believe somehow this site is still able to access this Google dictionary API though I don't know what url to try and/or if anyone has a suggestion for a different Dictionary API.

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one wondering about this!

Comment: The service seems to be shutdown. It doesn't work anymore, at least on that endpoint.

Comment: @Pathsofdesign I made API of this, see the answer below.

Comment: @snippetsofcode See my answer below.

Comment: https://googledictionaryapi.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/ Not to be use in production version, as it might get blocked due to scrapping google.

Comment: ^ That link violated Google's terms of service by scraping the google search result page for _"define <word>"_. This will get rate limited extremely quickly.

Comment: @Cerbrus is right, you can use it for yourself, and limit number of searches. What really matter is frequency of you using it.

Answer (score 3):

This service is no longer free, it is still the same API, but you have to pay to let you use it in your site or application. better to use an alternative solution like

http://glosbe.com/a-api